# How to create persistent urlsession in Swift?

Tags: swift

In Python, I can create a persistent session using `s = requests.Session()`. I have searched online how to do the same thing in Swift but nothing is working for me. I keep getting authentication errors.

Comment: What is a "persistent session"?

Comment: The idea is that you either use [`URLSession.shared`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1409000-shared), or you have a property that is a custom `URLSession` and you repeatedly use that. And it depends a little upon how your server is doing authentication (e.g. is it setting a cookie, or is it simply returning some authentication key that you have to manually include in the header of subsequent requests, or is it doing something completely different). There’s simply not enough here for us to help you. We need to see what you’ve tried, at the very least.